# PA state tax for CA income as an F-1 student (nonresident alien)

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, f1-student-visa, pennsylvania

I'm currently studying in PA on F-1 visa and have earned my only income last year from CA (internship while on CPT). I understand I should file state tax with CA as a nonresident. But I'm confused with my residency status at PA. I learned that [PA treats foreigners the same as citizens for tax purpose, and students should consider their parents for their state residency](https://global.upenn.edu/isss/tax). But since I'm a nonresident alien, does this mean I should consider my home country to be my permanent residence? As a result, no state tax form needs to be filed with PA?